# Unable to disable rules

Tags: eclipse, pmd

I'm a bit puzzled about using PMD in Eclipse.

I've removed and added rules from my ruleset but looks like PMD is not taking into account my changes, but only for removed rules, that is, it applies my new rules while checking, but still applies the removed rules too.

Also when I click *"Clear violation reviews"* it simply does nothing.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Me too! Also, if I right click on a violation in the Violations Outline the option to "Disable Rule" is greyed out.